# Is there a cleaner way to chain these Bluebird promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring, promise, bluebird

I have three functions (A, B, C) that each return a promise.  The chain of promises don't require any information from the previous promises except that they complete.

B has to wait for A to finish, and C has to wait for B to finish.

Currently I have:

```
return A(thing)
.then(function () {
  return B(anotherThing);
})
.then(function () {
  return C(somethingElse);
});
```

This feels like I'm wasting a lot of space (7 lines for what is really only 3 lines of actual code).

Comment: For one, you don't need to use 7 lines of code to express this same code.  I'd personally put the `.then()` on the same line as the one before it saving two lines.  Others might put the anonymous functions all on one line which can indeed collapse it down to 3 lines that is just as readable.

Comment: Note.  This question might be appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `works`

```
return A(thing)
    .then(B.bind(null,anotherThing))
    .then(C.bind(null,somethingElse));
```

note: bind is not available on IE8 or earlier - but there's a polyfill - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

For info - in ES2015 you could do - iojs will let you enable arrow functions, but they are apparently broken in some way

```
return A(thing)
    .then(() => B(anotherThing))
    .then(() => C(somethingElse));
```

Comment: OP is running on node.js so probably IE8 will not be an issue. Nice answer though.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - I knew that, I just have a habit of putting down IE :p

Comment: Since this is just a small, for fun project, I figure I play around with ES2015 using babel